# How can I invert selected items in a listbox?

Tags: user-interface, listbox, autohotkey

I have created a simple script with GUI in AutoHotkey. There is an multiple selection listbox with long list of items. I would like to create "invert selection button there".

I have found following messages:

```
PostMessage, 0x185, 1, -1, ListBox1  ; Select all items. 0x185 is LB_SETSEL.
PostMessage, 0x185, 0, -1, ListBox1  ; Deselect all items.
```

Is there something similar for "Invert Selection"?
If not, how can I script such thing in AutoHotkey?

Comment: why do you use `PostMessage` (tool for editing any window, even outside ahk) instead of `GuiControl` (tool for editing GUI elements of the current ahk gui)?

Comment: Loop through all elements and have a constant check if the element is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I provide here some code that should meet your requirements.
I have been working on a library of GUI Functions,
and have just completed work on some ListBox functions,
including `JEE_ListBoxInvSel(hCtl)`.

Here is some example code, with the functions below.
I have tested everything quite thoroughly. Do leave a comment
if there are any problems.

```
^q::
ControlGet, hCtl, Hwnd, , ListBox1, A
vList = 1,3,7
JEE_ListBoxSetSel(hCtl, vList, "ds")
Sleep 2000

MsgBox % JEE_ListBoxGetSel(hCtl)
Sleep 2000

JEE_ListBoxInvSel(hCtl)
Sleep 2000
JEE_ListBoxInvSel(hCtl)
Sleep 2000
JEE_ListBoxInvSel(hCtl)
Sleep 2000
MsgBox done
Return

;==================================================

;selected GUI functions by jeeswg

;JEE_ListBoxInvertSelection
;JEE_ListBoxSetSelInv
JEE_ListBoxInvSel(hCtl)
{
SendMessage, 0x18B, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_GETCOUNT
vCount := ErrorLevel
SendMessage, 0x190, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_GETSELCOUNT
vCountSel := ErrorLevel

if (vCount-vCountSel > vCountSel)
vList := JEE_ListBoxGetSel(hCtl, 1), JEE_ListBoxSetSel(hCtl, vList, "sd")
else
vList := JEE_ListBoxGetSel(hCtl, 0), JEE_ListBoxSetSel(hCtl, vList, "ds")
Return
}

;==================================================

;returns 1-based index of focused item
JEE_ListBoxGetFocus(hCtl)
{
;LB_GETCARETINDEX := 0x19F
SendMessage, 0x19F, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_GETCARETINDEX
Return ErrorLevel+1
}

;sets 1-based index of focused item
JEE_ListBoxSetFocus(hCtl, vNum, vOpt=0)
{
;LB_SETCARETINDEX := 0x19E
SendMessage, 0x19E, vNum-1, 0, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_SETCARETINDEX
Return
}

;==================================================

;returns a comma-separated list of 1-based indexes for selected items
;JEE_ListBoxGetSelectedItems
JEE_ListBoxGetSel(hCtl, vOpt=1)
{
;LB_GETCOUNT := 0x18B
;LB_GETSELCOUNT := 0x190
;LB_GETSELITEMS := 0x191

SendMessage, 0x190, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_GETSELCOUNT
vCountSel := ErrorLevel
VarSetCapacity(vBuf, 32*vCountSel)
SendMessage, 0x191, vCountSel, &vBuf, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_GETSELITEMS
vRet := ErrorLevel

Loop, %vRet%
vOutput .= (NumGet(vBuf, A_Index*4-4, "UInt")+1) ","
vOutput := SubStr(vOutput, 1, -1) ;trim right

if (vOpt = 0)
{
SendMessage, 0x18B, , , , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_GETCOUNT
vCount := ErrorLevel
Loop, %vCount%
if A_Index not in %vOutput%
vOutput2 .= A_Index ","
vOutput2 := SubStr(vOutput2, 1, -1) ;trim right
Return vOutput2
}

Return vOutput
}

;==================================================

;description:
;hCtl: handle to ListBox control

;vList: comma-separated list of items (1-based index)
;e.g. '1,3,5' (select the 1st,3rd,5th items)
;e.g. '3' (select the 3rd item)

;vOpt: s/d/sd/ds/sa/da
;s select items in list
;d deselect items in list
;sd select all items and deselect items in list
;ds deselect all items and select items in list
;sa select all items
;da deselect all items

;JEE_ListBoxSelectItems
JEE_ListBoxSetSel(hCtl, vList, vOpt="s")
{
;LB_SETSEL := 0x185

if vOpt in sa,sd
SendMessage, 0x185, 1, -1, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_SETSEL
if vOpt in da,ds
SendMessage, 0x185, 0, -1, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_SETSEL
if vOpt in sa,da
Return

if vOpt in s,ds
vState := 1
if vOpt in d,sd
vState := 0

Loop, Parse, vList, `,
SendMessage, 0x185, vState, A_LoopField-1, , ahk_id %hCtl% ;LB_SETSEL
Return
}

;==================================================
```

Comment: Where is this library? I'd love to see it!

Comment: Check references to graphical user interfaces, here. I hope to consolidate my GUI projects later this year.
jeeswg's homepage - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=30931